# implementing images in certain questions for my quiz application

Tags: kotlin, multiple-choice

Im creating my own app for a couple of weeks now, so im kinda new to this.
Everything i did so far, i could do without help except googling stuff,
but this is too complex now.
I made an app, that lets me add more and more questions, but i can only put in 4 answers
and only one of them may be correct. I also wanna make questions with multiple correct answers,
but i dont know how. Also for mathematical questions, i wanna implement pictures with formulas
but when i make the code for it, im supposed to have a picture in all of my questions.
Sometimes i want 1 correct answer, sometimes i want to have 5 correct answers.
Sometimes i want to have a picture in my questions, sometimes i dont.

Can you guys help me with that?

I tryed googling, but i cannot find a solution for it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nl18.jpg)
This is how my quiz looks like. Ive put in 4 fields for answers, i wanna be flexible with 2-6 fields but cannot manage to code it correctly.

Thanks in advance
)

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find a ready-to-go solution for something so specific, and you have a few different questions in here. You probably want to think about *how you can represent your question* as a data structure, and then build a UI that works with that structure and displays the appropriate stuff.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
data class Question(
    val promptText: String,
    val promptImage: Uri? = null,
    val correctAnswers: List<String>,
    val wrongAnwers: List<String>
)
```

That way you have a representation of all the data you need to define a question and its answers:

- A required question text
- An optional question image (nullable so it can be missing, null by default so you can use named arguments and skip specifying null for the image if you want)
- A list of possible right answers
- A list of possible wrong answers

Then it's just a case of your UI making use of that! It can display the question text, show any provided image in an ImageView (e.g. using `setImageUri`) or hide it if there isn't one, and rearrange the correct/incorrect answers as required for display in buttons. You could even randomly pick X correct answers and Y wrong answers if you have enough to mix it up, generate different problems from each of your source `Question` data objects.

Showing a varying numbers of buttons is a little trickier, there are lots of ways to do it, but the easiest might be adding the max (say 6) if you know what the limit is, and just giving the unused ones a visibility of `GONE`. Or you could use Compose or a RecyclerView to display a button for each item in your answer list. Pros and cons to both, so it's something to look into. Don't be afraid to google stuff! It's a way to learn

If you're looking to actually generate the equation images in the app, you'll have to find a library to do that. If you're pre-generating them, you'll have to store them and load them in - [the recommended approach](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) is to use a library like *Glide*.